# Ecto returns numbers in scientific (exponential) notation

Tags: elixir, ecto

I don't know if it's an Ecto's or Elixir's issue. When I have a number in database like 1000, 15000 etc. Ecto returns it as 1.0e3, 1.5e4... If I change that 1000 to 1234 everything is ok.

Elixir 1.3.2, Ecto 2.0.3, MySQL

Migration:

```
alter table(:incoming_transfers) do
  add :fee, :float # Ecto translates it as DOUBLE in MySQL
end
```

Schema:

```
schema "incoming_transfers" do
  field :fee, :float
end
```

If I change manually in my database type DOUBLE to FLOAT the problem remains. But if I change it to INTEGER, it's good.

Comment: What type did you use for that column in the migration for the table and the schema declaration in the model? Can you please include the relevant snippets of both of those files in the question?

Comment: @Dogbert I have updated my question

Comment: So - maybe it's a stupid question- why you want to keep integer numbers as floats? Just use integer in schema.

Comment: @PatNowak this was just an example. When I had this issue for the first time, I fixed this by converting Float to [Money](https://github.com/liuggio/money), but now I must to use Float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who want to override function mentioned by @Dogbert. Just put it in your code:

```
defimpl Inspect, for: Float do
  def inspect(term, _opts) do
    IO.iodata_to_binary(:io_lib_format.fwrite_g(term))
  end
end
```

and change `:io_lib_format.fwrite_g(term)` to something like `:erlang. float_to_binary(term, [decimals: 6])`. 
For example, for `7.12` it returns `"7.120000"`.

Anyway, I think it would be better to use [Decimal](https://github.com/ericmj/decimal) instead of Float.

Answer (score 2):

Elixir's `Inspect` implementation for `Float` [just delegates to `:io_lib_format.fwrite_g/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/c38775f9008e540ae41e734d74bc27b2aa77c715/lib/elixir/lib/inspect.ex#L410) and [`:io_lib_format.fwrite_g/1`'s source in Erlang/OTP](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/e43e82802735f2fd0d6d67308e7602c37ac70898/lib/stdlib/src/io_lib_format.erl#L447-L462) mentions that it tries to print the number accurately in the least number of characters possible. So, `1000` is converted to `1.0e3` because that's shorter than `1000.0`, but `100.0` is not converted to `1.0e2` because that's not shorter than `100.0`. Similarly `12300.0` is converted to `1.23e4` because that's shorter.

```
%%  Writes the shortest, correctly rounded string that converts
%%  to Float when read back with list_to_float/1.
%%
%%  See also "Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately"
%%  in Proceedings of the SIGPLAN '96 Conference on Programming
%%  Language Design and Implementation.
```

Erlang:

```
1> [1000.0, 100.0, 12300.0].
[1.0e3,100.0,1.23e4]
```

Note that this does *not* result in losing any accuracy (beyond what floating numbers already lose). `1000.0` is exactly equal to `1.0e3`.